# Stripe : Issuing balance, Customer balance, Platform balance

Tags: stripe-payments

Im trying to find connection between Issuing balance, Customer balance and Platform balance.

What I did until now:

1. I have created customer and added balance to that customer.
2. I have created Card holder
3. created virtual card for card holder
4. Top-up account with 'destination_balance' => 'issuing',
5. created source (added customer and type=card [first try]; second type= ach_credit_transfer])
6. Finally I have created charge

Now, I can track charges by checking credit card transactions, BUT HOW can I track how much resources is available on customer after charges.
My customer balance is always the same when I make charges per source/card or else...
Is it possible to top-up issuing using customer balance...? Is it possible to connect it somehow so I can check customer balance every time when payment is made through issuing...?
Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong...or what I misunderstand.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Can you explain some more? Customer balances are related to invoice credits and outstanding amounts owing. Are you confusing a Customer with a connected Account?

Comment: Customer balances only apply to invoiced items like subscriptions. They don't apply to charges.

Comment: @NolanH I need to "attach" issuing cards with a customers so I can track how much money is spent per each customer. I need something to "top-up" issuing for specific user from customer balance. I can have multiple customers on my platform and each of them can have multiple cards/card holders/... I have found easy solution to use issuing cards and top-up them from "global" account,.. in that case I cant track how much money is spent per customer...and logic is created around cusrtomer.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore yes, I saw that. Customer balance updates after invoicing.

Comment: @NolanH you are probably right, I also though that connect would be the best solution. Is there any solution with stripe issuing that can make current business logic possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about multiple things:

1. Tracking total spend across some sort of grouping of Issued cards.
2. Topping up the issuing balance for a pool of cards.

I'm not sure how this maps to your business model, but you may find it helpful to consider using [Connect and custom accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) for these groupings. This would allow you to have [cardholders per account](https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/funding/connect#making-requests-on-behalf-of-connected-accounts) and [manage an issuing balance per account](https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/funding/connect#add-funds).